# Trigger sem replicar os dados - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, query, trigger

Galera, tenho uma trigger na tabela FRM_46 que seria para replicar os dados logo após o insert ou update para a tabela FRM_31, porém, não está replicando, já analisei e fiz os testes, porém, não consegui verificar onde está o erro.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TGR_FORMULARIO_REPLICAÇÃO_NOVO_PROCESSO_ESTRATEGICO]
   ON [dbo].[FRM_46] 
    AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @TarefaID  INT,
    @DataDoPerfilCliente nVARCHAR(15),
    @PerfilCliente nVARCHAR(15),
    @ContaID INT


    BEGIN
        SELECT  @TarefaID = F.TarefaID,
                @DataDoPerfilCliente = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),103),
                @ContaID = t.UsuIDCliente,
                @PerfilCliente = f.C33
        FROM inserted F
        INNER JOIN Tarefa T on t.TarID = f.ChamadoID

        IF @ContaID NOT IN (SELECT ContaID FROM FRM_31)
            INSERT INTO FRM_31 (ContaID, C01, C02, C05) VALUES (@ContaID, @DataDoPerfilCliente, @PerfilCliente, @TarefaID);
        IF @ContaID IN (SELECT ContaID FROM FRM_31)
            UPDATE FRM_31 SET C01 = @DataDoPerfilCliente, C02 = @PerfilCliente, C05 = @TarefaID, C08 = null WHERE ContaID = @ContaID
    END
END
```

Comment: Sugestão inicial: leitura da série “Armadilhas na programação de procedimentos de gatilho”, publicada em https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/38010.armadilhas-na-programacao-de-procedimentos-de-gatilho.aspx

Comment: Coloque um exemplo do `insert` que não está tendo o resultado esperado, por favor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A `TRIGGER` demonstrada só irá executar uma vez, independente da quantidade de registros inseridos ou alterados. Para alterar pensando em vários registros sugiro o seguinte:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.tgr_formulario_replicação_novo_processo_estrategico
   ON dbo.frm_46
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  MERGE frm_31 AS destino
  USING (SELECT f.tarefaid,
                CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS data,
                t.usuidcliente,
                f.c33
          FROM inserted f
               INNER JOIN tarefa t ON t.tarid = f.chamadoid) AS origem
     ON (destino.contaid = origem.usuidcliente)
  -- Quando encontrar um registro que corresponda, apenas atualiza com os valores que constam aqui
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
       SET destino.c01 = origem.data,
           destino.c02 = origem.c33,
           destino.c05 = origem.tarefaid,
           destino.c08 = null
  -- Quando não encontrar irá inserir
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (contaid,
            c01,
            c02,
            c05)
    VALUES (origem.usuidcliente,
            origem.data,
            origem.c33,
            origem.tarefaid);
END;
GO
```

No código demonstrado acima verificamos a existência de um registro na tabela de destino com o mesmo `ContaID`. Caso exista, o caso `MATCHED` é executado, atualizando o registro existente. Caso não exista na tabela de destino (`FRM_31`), o caso `NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` é executado, inserindo um novo registro.

Note também que você só está utilizando a coluna `ContaID` como chave, portanto caso exista um novo registro, porém com um `ContaID` já existente, a linha na tabela `FRM_31` será apenas atualizada.

---

> [**`MERGE`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql)
>
> Realiza operações de inserção, atualização ou exclusão em uma tabela de destino com base nos resultados da junção com a tabela de origem. Por exemplo, você pode sincronizar duas tabelas inserindo, atualizando ou excluindo linhas em uma tabela com base nas diferenças encontradas na outra tabela.

Comment: Show de bola @Sorack, funcionou direitinho.